# Avoid publishing of file in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I am working on an API on .Net 6, which publishes to a server. It creates its own settings file if missing, and I have also a file on my computer with settings for my current progress in work.

The file is set to "Do not copy", and I have this in my project file for both debug and Release.

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>settings.config</ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

However, VS2022 really likes this file and publishes it every time. The file is not even in the project, but VS lists it when it appears. Therefore I sent it to "Do not copy"
Also, I do not like to overwrite what settings they might have in the live server

How can I avoid publishing of certain files?
I googled and found the idea for the PropertyGroup, but that does not work

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Update="settings.config">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory> <!-- by VS itself -->
    <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory> <!-- add this line -->
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```